# Audio terminology for "rising frequency"?

Tags: audio, terminology

Left is scalogram of exponential chirp, right is of a bunch of these within time shifts ([Shepard Tone](https://youtu.be/BzNzgsAE4F0)):

[image]

Is there audio terminology for describing this, besides "rising frequency"? Rising pitch? Rising timbre? Would the two cases be described with different phrases (ignore cross-fading etc for the right case, just focusing on the rising aspect)?

The idea's to describe any positive slope in time-frequency - I have a method that does it, and would like an audio-friendly wording to label it. It should also go the other way, for "falling frequency".

Comment: Maybe a _sweep_ ?

Comment: @audionuma I seek to replace "frequency", "rising" / "falling" should stay. "Rising sweep"... doesn't quite work for me.

Comment: That "Shepard Tone" is really cool! Wish I could upvote twice. Happy New Year

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few points:

1. Rising or falling frequency is fine (IMO). For sweeps people often use "up" sweep or "down" sweep.
2. The slope of a linear sweep can be measured in $Hz/s$ for a log sweep it's better to use "octaves per second".
3. "Timbre" is definitely wrong here. Timbre is a perceptual quantity that's related to certain frequency areas of high vs low energy but not to the fundamental frequency or pitch.
4. "Frequency" is a physical quantity. "Pitch" is a perceptual quantity. They are both related but they are definitely not the same. Case in point: The Shephard Tone is an example of where they disagree. The frequency follows a sawtooth wave, but the pitch is continuously rising. The "jump back" of the frequency is not audible. Another one is "missing fundamental". If you have a signal made up of 200Hz, 300Hz, 400Hz, .. the perceived pitch will be that of a 100Hz sine wave despite the signal not containing any energy at 100Hz at all.
5. Best practice: if you describing something physical use a physical terminology, if you describing human perception use a perceptual quantity.

Comment: Right, I wondered if I was missing some basic terminology, guess not. Good distinction on physical vs perceptual.

Comment: I don't believe your description of the shepherd tone is quite right.  The tone obscures where the jump in pitch is, but there still is a jump in pitch, you would not describe the pitch as being in the 10th octave after listening to a few repetitions.